# Identifiy customer with no activity during 6 months and then reactivation of the account

Tags: teradata

I have one table with a lot of columns and with the following ones :

customer_id | Transaction_ID | Transaction DATE

For each customer ID we have several transactions and the transactions are not in chronological order.

I would like to find the customers that did not have any transaction during 6 months (or more) and then did one or more transactions after this dormant period.
I would like to have all the customers meeting this requirements starting from January 2015.

I am using Teradata SQL assistant since few months and I am not sure how to process this. Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done using conditional aggregation:

```
select customer_id
from tab
group by customer_id
       -- transactions before start
having sum(case when Transaction_Date < date '2015-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
       -- transactions after end
   and sum(case when Transaction_Date > date '2015-06-30' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
       -- no transactions between start and end 
   and sum(case when Transaction_Date between date '2015-01-01' and date '2015-06-30' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```